# Preload ajax loaded content

Tags: ajax, jquery, preloading

On my site I use one core/frame PHP file. If user hit one of my link (like contact, our about..etc..) the content loaded via ajax. I use the following snippet to achieve this:

```
var AjaxContent = function(){
    var container_div = ''; 
    var content_div = ''; 
    return {
        getContent : function(url){
            $(container_div).animate({opacity:0}, 
                function(){ // the callback, loads the content with ajax
                    $(container_div).load(url, //only loads the selected portion
                        function(){                        
                           $(container_div).animate({opacity:1}); 
                    }

                );        
            });
        },
        ajaxify_links: function(elements){
            $(elements).click(function(){
                AjaxContent.getContent(this.href);
                                    

                return false; 
                
            });
        },
        init: function(params){ 
            container_div = params.containerDiv; 
            content_div = params.contentDiv;
            
            return this; 
        }
    }
}();
```

I need help how to integrate a preloading, so if visitors hit one of my link (for example the gallery menu) will see a little loading image, because now they see the big white nothing for long - long seconds.

Comment: well, instead of the white page, why don't you provide a loading gif? also, if it takes long seconds, you might want to optimize the server-side code, since page speed load [has a lot of impact on people today](http://blog.tagman.com/2012/03/just-one-second-delay-in-page-load-can-cause-7-loss-in-customer-conversions/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add loading image beforing ajax call and after you get response from server simply replace that image with data like the one below

```
 function(){ // the callback, loads the content with ajax
        $(container_div).html("<img src='loading.gif' />");//add image before ajax call
        $(container_div).load(url, //only loads the selected portion
        function(){
         $(container_div).html(data);//replace image with server response data                        
        $(container_div).animate({opacity:1}); 
    }
```

Comment: r ya sure this work? i tried, but not seen the image...check with firebug and the image path is ok.

Comment: this definitely works but make sure image should load i.e image size matters and how quick you gonna get ajax content

Comment: So. I have many images in this content. Now when i hit the link i get white page for secnds, then the loader image come, and few sencods later content loaded. 
What do you suggest, when user hit the link, the loader image show immediately?

Comment: do one thing preload an loader image like this <div style="display:none"><img src="loader.gif" /></div> add this div tag in your html page any where. Then while you first load your html page and hit button to get ajax content the loader.gif image immediately pop's up

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var AjaxContent = function(){
    var container_div = ''; 
    var content_div = ''; 
    return {
        getContent : function(url){
            $(container_div).html('Loading...');  //replace with your loading img html code
            $(container_div).load(url, //only loads the selected portion
                function(){
                    $(container_div).css({opacity:0});
                    $(container_div).animate({opacity:1}); 
            });
        },
        ajaxify_links: function(elements){
            $(elements).click(function(){
                AjaxContent.getContent(this.href);


                return false; 

            });
        },
        init: function(params){ 
            container_div = params.containerDiv; 
            content_div = params.contentDiv;

            return this; 
        }
    }
}();
```